# Unable to access cvs public repository anonymous access

Tags: gitlab, cvs, cvs2git

I am trying to migrate cvs to git repository. I tried to test how it works. So I tried to access cvs public repository using the [doc](http://luonnotar.infodrom.org/cvs.html)

There is support to access cvs repositories with an anonymous account with an empty password, but I am unable to access it.

```
cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@cvs.infodrom.org:/var/cvs/$repository login

Logging in to :pserver:anonymous@cvs.infodrom.org:2401/var/cvs/config

CVS password: 

cvs [login aborted]: unrecognized auth response from cvs.infodrom.org: /usr/bin/cvs: unrecognized option '--allow_root=/var/cvs/debian'
```

How can I access cvs repository with an anonymous user?

Comment: (I haven't heard back, did you get this to work? Was my post helpful?)

Comment: No, Its not working.. Mort..

Comment: @Mort, Is there any steps to configure server-side and client-side to access cvs repository?

Comment: By server side I mean you need access to the server's filesystem. If you're converting a repo to git, presumably you're an admin of the cvs repo already so it's not an issue. If you don't have that, maybe you can get the admin to tar up the whole repo for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Try using `infodrom` rather than `config` as a `$repository` value as that's what's documented here: http://www.infodrom.org/projects/cfingerd/cvs.php and in similar projects i.e.

   cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@cvs.infodrom.org:/var/cvs/infodrom login
2. You normally need the whole server-side repo to do a proper cvs2git, not just a client-side checkout. Which you cannot get from a repo on the web, you can only get if you are the sysadmin on your own cvs repo.

Comment: Mort,
 [1] I am getting the same error when I use infodrom instead of $repository
[2] I am not sure that I have configured properly. Is there any documentation for configuration to access cvs repo as anonymous?

Comment: It could also be that infodrom cvs is somehow mis-configured.